How to fix MISRA issue 14.3
I have this part of code, in the codebase, and while running coverity I have come up with an MISRA issue 14.3.
typedef uint8_t INSTANCE;

#define INSTANCE_1  (0U)
#define INSTANCE_2  (1U)
...
#define INSTANCE_11 (11U)

int fun(INSTANCE x)
{
  // I am getting the MISRA issue Controlling expression "0U <= x" is invariant.
  if (INSTANCE_1 <= x && x <= INSTANCE_11) {
          do_something()
  }
}

Not sure how to fix this MISRA issue 14.3.

The variable x can't be negative, i.e. it can't be less than zero. So INSTANCE_1 <= x will always be true. You should remove that check.

I wonder what MISRA expects you to do if there are some other configurations where INSTANCE_1 has a nonzero value.

And this is another reason why you don't hide types with typedef.  It's not readily apparent that INSTANCE (hello FORTRAN77?) is an unsigned type.  If you need to show that the variable is an INSTANCE, that's what the name of the variable is for.  Hiding the type of the variable hides critical information from the programmer.  And in this case it opens the door to some really nasty bugs should typedef uint8_t INSTANCE; ever be changed to something like typedef int16_t INSTANCE; to handle more INSTANCEs.

@NateEldredge Since MISRA C is used for safety-critical system, it is applied to the code base as-is. There can be no dead code, commented-out code, compiler switches etc etc. If you need to reconfigure a program you either design that in (by means of volatile eeprom etc) or make a separate build/branch and apply MISRA compliance on that one separately.

As your INSTANCE variable is of type uint8_t and INSTANCE_1 is defined as 0U, there is no way that INSTANCE is less than 0.
int fun(INSTANCE x)
{
  if (INSTANCE_1 <= x && x <= INSTANCE_11) {
     do_something();
  }
}

To fix the MISRA violation in this specific example you could simply remove the condition INSTANCE_1 <= x from the if statement.
int fun(INSTANCE x)
{
  if (x <= INSTANCE_11) {
     do_something();
  }
}


As I noted above, this does open the door to some nasty problems should INSTANCE ever be redefined to a signed type.  I'm thinking an enum would likely be better, but since we don't have the full context here, an enum might not be appropriate.
